# Calculate tire stress

Tags: friction, stress-strain

I'm trying to figure out how much stress is experienced by a tire while driving. Each tire can carry a maximum amount of weight, for a tire of 98kg this is 750kg per tire. A Tesla Model 3 weighs in at 1,611kg. I'm trying to calculate the stress on each tire while the Tesla is driving 80km/h but am not sure how I can calculate this?

Comment: The stress is going to vary significantly depending on which part of the tire you're interested in. The "stress on the tire" is probably too broad a notion to answer.

Comment: The stress will also vary greatly depending on the tire construction.  A tire is not just rubber, so you have plies, belts, cords, etc. all made of various materials.  The stress in a given tire will also depend on the inflation pressure.  Calculating the stresses in a tire is something that is probably only done by tire manufacturers using specialized FEA codes, with varying degrees of accuracy.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. In this case I want to know how much stress is experienced by a piezo element placed on the outer band on the inside of the tire. Next step would be to link this to the possible power output of the piezo element based on this stress.

Comment: Please note that it don't need to be precise, I need an estimation as I want to know if this idea I'm having is feasible.

Comment: @rvrbk Good idea about a piezoelectric element. We can probably use it to recharge the battery, but the current there will be small. I can calculate the stress using FEM.

Comment: Ok, if you're interested can you help me with the calculation? You can also reach me on rvrbk.dev@gmail.com.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for an estimate of the circumferential **strain** on the inside of the tread portion of the tire as the car is driving.  Of course there will be an initial positive strain due to tire inflation.  Below, I will estimate the additional positive strain generated when your piezo element rotates from the top position to the bottom (adjacent to the road) position.

The top gray annulus represents the tire when unloaded.  The red line represents your element.  The thickness $t$ is the distance from the inside of the tire at $R_i$ to the outside of the tire at the tread.  Assume your element spans an angle of $\theta$ radians.

The bottom rectangle represents the same portion of the tire in contact with the ground.  This portion of the tire has been flattened out by the car weight.  We assume that the centerline of the cross-section shown in blue does not change length.  The accuracy of this assumption would depend on the exact construction and tread pattern.

When flattened out, the inside of the tire is stretched circumferentially and the outside of the tire is compressed.

The unloaded element length is

$L_0 = \theta{}R_i$.

The loaded element length is

$L_1 = \theta{}(R_i + t/2)$

**The change in strain during driving is therefore**

$\delta = L_1 / L_0 - 1 = ((R_i - t/2) / R_i) - 1$

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I must admit I'm kind of a noob so I need some time to decode this ;)

Comment: @rvrbk: No problem.  Imagine you have a thick, curved piece of rubber (as in my top image) and you flatten it out.  The middle plain will stay the same length.  The top surface will have to stretch and the bottom will compress.  The top, middle, and bottom will all be the same length after flattening.  This method calculates the stretch (strain) in the top surface.  Good luck!

Comment: So if I know how much weight is on the tire I can figure out how much this is while driving using your method?

Comment: @rvrbk: This method assumes that there is enough weight to flatten out a section of the tire at the tire footprint.  This is true of normal car tires.  For example, see the pressure distribution image at the following site.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_patch  I think the exact car weight will not affect the strain much.